# Make an element minus the height of another element in css without display flex

Tags: css

Make an element minus the height of another element in css without display flex. Because flex is a new thing, it is not supported in some browsers which is worrying.

So I have two elements:

```
<div id="example1">
hello there<br>some text
</div>
<div id="example2">
hi there<br>this is some more text<br>to make this thing more lengthy
</div>
```

So, because of the text inside `#example2`, if `#example2` is for example: `100px` in height, I want to make the div `#example1`: 100% of page height minus the height of `#example2`, `100% - height@#example2`

### Edit:

If there is no way without flex, let me know.

Comment: Nice hint: Flexbox is not a new thing ... it is supported well on ALL actual (released up from 2015) browser(versions). That means: only less then ca. 0.02% off all browsers worldwide does not support it. Please check yourself: https://caniuse.com/?search=flexbox. That means: if you do have a solution in flexbox it is not a problem to use it.

Comment: Flex isn't that new, really. It has a [99.07% coverage](https://www.caniuse.com/?search=flex). In your case, you can just do `calc(100vh - 100px)`...

Comment: @AmauryHanser but the height can be random dependent on the text in the div

Comment: read *all* the duplicate and you find non-flex solution

Answer (score 0):

You are able to calculate in CSS which is really cool and a much younger feature than flexbox. But head up: that needs a fixed height for the bottom div.

Here the example:

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.top {
    height: calc(100% - 100px);
    background: green;
}
.bottom {
    height: 100px;
    background: darkgreen;
}
```

```html
    <div class="top">Div top</div>
    <div class="bottom">Div bottom</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using JavaScript then you can use `.getBoundingClientRect().height` on the element in question and set the element's height to `element1.style.height = "calc(100vh - " + element2.getBoundingClientRect().height + "px)";`

This is, of course, if you don't already know the height of `element1`, if you do then this can just be done with CSS!

Comment: I cannot use inline css btw. Will this work with the linked stylesheets

Comment: This is JavaScript! So as long as you execute it after the elements have loaded and been laid out, then it will grab the element's height and adjust the other element accordingly. It's not CSS at all. (Although the JavaScript does edit a CSS attribute, it's not CSS code.)